# AttributeError: RFBNetworkClient instance has no attribute 'clipping'

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start a video using castro lib but I'm facing this error which is very annoying

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 258, in _bootstrap self.run() File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 114, in run self._target(self._args, *self._kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/castro-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/castro/lib/pyvnc2swf/vnc2swf.py",
> line 611, in main merge=merge, debug=debug, reconnect=reconnect) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/castro-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/castro/lib/pyvnc2swf/vnc2swf.py",
> line 429, in vnc2swf client.loop() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/castro-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/castro/lib/pyvnc2swf/rfb.py", line 489, in loop if not self.loop1(): break File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/castro-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/castro/lib/pyvnc2swf/rfb.py", line 276, in loop1 self.request_update() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/castro-1.0.6-py2.7.egg/castro/lib/pyvnc2swf/rfb.py", line 551, in request_update self.send('\x03\x01' + pack('>HHHH',
> *self.clipping)) AttributeError: RFBNetworkClient instance has no attribute 'clipping'
```

Here is my code for the video

```
from selenium import webdriver, selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import castro

class Video(object):
   def init(self, args, *kwargs):
      self.verificationErrors = []
      self.video = castro.Castro()
      self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      super(Video, self).init() 

def manager_video(self):
    self.video.start()
    self.driver.get('http://www.n1ght.com')
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("appendedInputButton")
    element.send_keys("brussel")
    self.driver.close()
    self.video.stop()
    self.video.process()
```

How to solve this issue? Help!!!

Comment: Any chance you ever figured out the problem with this? I'm getting the same thing, running python 2.7 on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: It's pretty much saying vnc client is not correctly connected.